# is it possible to use Amazon Forecast without Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-forecast

I am learning the Forecast tool and would like to know if it is possible to use Forecast without S3?
Send the data directly to forecast without going through the s3 bucket.

If possible, could you give me an example?
thanks!

All the information I have read says that it is necessary to use the amazon S3 bucket, but I do not lose anything by asking if it is possible to avoid that step.

Comment: Which particular API call? If the documentation says "Required", then it is required. Can I ask... why do you not wish to use S3?

Comment: It's not possible. [To import your data to an Amazon Forecast dataset, you must store it in an Amazon S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/forecast/latest/dg/getting-started.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein try to cut costs

Comment: Amazon S3 storage is very low cost. You can always delete the objects after use. It would likely cost a few cents a year for such short-term storage.